# Restrict api key for firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to restrict the access to a Firestore DB so that only a specific Android App can access it.
I went to Firebase console and in my Project settings I added my App. I added google-services.json to the app.
In google cloud console I see that I get 2 keys:
Android key (auto created by Firebase)
Browser key (auto created by Firebase)
My idea was to restrick the Android key with my app fingerprint.
What happens is that no matter which fingerprint I add, or even if I restrict the key by website instead of Android App I am always able to access the firestore DB for reading and writing from my Android App.
And even if I put a dummy api_key in my google-services.json file, I still can acess the database.

What am I missing?

Note: I don't want to restrick the access by user authentication. My goal is to restrict by my specific android App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to restrict an API key to a specific Android app, and the Firebase documentation on [using and managing API keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys) also doesn't show such a feature.

The closest equivalent is to enable [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) on the project, and then [set up Ap Check only on your Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider).

This will act as a broad deterrent for a lot of abuse, but will not completely rule it out across platforms. For that reason, I still recommend [implementing user-based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) in your project too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Frank! You say that App Check "will not completely rule out across platforms". Can you give a significant example?